# ftp Windows 10 брандмауэр

Tags: ftp, firewall

Брандмауэр не дает подключиться к FTP!
Хотя вроде все описанные инструкции сделал а то есть в входящих и исходящих правилах включил:

1. Сервер ftp
2. Трафик ftp

Answer (score 0):

Протокол FTP использует несколько портов для своей работы: TCP 21 и ещё один динамический TCP-порт. Файерволы должны обрабатывать подобные случаи особым образом, используя [ALG](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-level_gateway). Имеет ли ваш брандмауер подобный функционал, я, увы, не в курсе.

Comment: Можете попробовать в настройках вашего FTP-сервер указать, что следует использовать Passive-режим. Возможно, это поможет.